# Only update readme for a package on PyPI

Tags: python, pypi, python-poetry

I published a package on PyPI and then realised I should change a few details in the attached `README.md`. Is it possible to change the readme without uploading a new version of the whole package? And if not, what is the most correct way to update the README on PyPI?

I am using `poetry` to manage the package, and when I change README and run `poetry publish --build`, there is an error, because PyPI does not allow re-uploading a file with an already used name.

It seems like only changing the documentation should be a possibility, as, e.g., writing some extra help or changing a contact should not require a whole round of changing version and testing that everything still works?

Comment: Unfortunately, no it isn't, because when you go to `publish`, the versions are immutable. This is by design. My suggestion would be to increment a minor version `z` on `x.y.z` in order to publish the latest version with updates to the README.

Comment: Is increasing the minor version preferable to, say, `x.y.z.post1`?

Comment: No, something like `x.y.(z+1)`, so `2.1.0` becomes `2.1.1`. `0.0.9` becomes `0.0.10`

Comment: @C.Nivs - this question is O.T., but I consider this to be a case of "Although practicality beats purity."- I think your comments could go as an answer here, lest we close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no it isn't, because when you go to publish, the versions are immutable. This is by design. My suggestion would be to increment a minor version `z` on `x.y.z` in order to publish the latest version with updates to the `README`.

So something like:
`0.0.9` -> `0.0.10`
or
`2.1.0` -> `2.1.1`

Answer (score 2):

You need to publish a new, updated release. And to publish it you need to increase version. You can increase micro version (`x.y.z+1`) but if the code was not changed you can just add a post-release suffix. The first suffix is `.post1`. I often do this, see https://pypi.org/project/CT3/3.3.0.post1/ as an example.